# KOTH: Everybody loves tokens

Tags: grid, king-of-the-hill, javascript

In this game two players compete to eat the most points worth of tokens, but there's a twist! Eating multiple tokens in a row of the same color gives an ever-growing bonus, but watch out, or your opponent will thwart your plans by eating the tokens you want before you can!

**Rules:**

- 1 versus 1
- n by n board (random size between 5x5 and 15x15)
- You and your opponent will spawn in the same random cell
- Throughout the board will be randomly generated numbers in some cells ranging in value from 1-3
- 2 * (the width of the board) tokens will be generated, but there can be overrides, so there may be fewer by chance.
- Each number will be one of 3 colors: Red, Green, or Blue, in hex RGB format
- Each round, player 1 moves and the board is updated, then player 2 moves, and the board is updated. So each player can effectively tell what move the previous player made based on the change in the board state. This continues until the game ends, as described later.
- You have 6 possible actions for a turn: UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT, EAT, and PASS
- The 4 move commands are self-explanatory, and you CAN pass your turn. If you return a nonsensical move, we will assume you meant pass. If you try to move off the edge of the board, you will not move. The edges don't wrap.
- EAT consumes the number you are currently in the same space as
- You gain as many points as the number you consume
- If you eat 2 numbers in a row of the same color, you get +1
- If you eat 3 numbers in a row of the same color, you get +2
- If you eat m numbers in a row of the same color, you get +(m-1)
- These bonuses are added cumulatively, so getting m numbers in a row leads to m*(m-1)/2 in total bonus by the time you eat a different color.
- Game end conditions:

  - All numbers are consumed
  - 4 * (the width of the board) turns have gone by with no effective eating (just saying “EAT” with no token where you are doesn't count) occurring by either player (any token is reachable in 2 * (the width) moves, so this bound will only be surpassed if both players have no single target token in mind)
- Your AI should take less than a second to make a move, else PASS will be assumed as your choice.

The tournament will be round robin with a large number of rounds, say 100 or 1000. A random board is generated, and each ordered pair of different players is run on that board. After the tournament completes we will rank people by their total score. So even if you are player 2 for a game, your goal is still to get as many points as possible.

**AI Submission:** The language my controller supports is Javascript. Multiple submissions are allowed. Everyone submits a constructor for an object like this:

```
function (player1) {
    this.yourMove = function (b) {
        return "MOVE";
    }
}
```

The input `player1` is a boolean saying whether you are player 1 or not.
Your constructor must have the `yourMove` function, but it can have
any number of additional functions or values as well. Don't define any
global variables, just put them as variables on your object. A new version
of your object will be created at the beginning of each match, and
`yourMove` will be called on it, with the current board as input, on each of your turns, and should return a valid move.

`b`, the input to `yourMove`, is a **copy** of the current board, here are the
constructors, with input examples, though you can't call them yourself:

```
function token(color, points) {
    this.color = color; //"#FF0000"
    this.points = points; //5
}

function player(pos, score, colorBonus, lastColor) {
    this.pos = pos; //[5, 5]
    this.score = score; //9
    this.colorBonus = colorBonus; //i.e. 2 if you just ate 3 blue tokens in a row
                                  //0 if you just ate two different colors.
    this.lastColor = lastColor; //"#00FF00", is "#000000" at start
}

function board(player1, player2, tokens) {
    this.player1 = player1; //new player([5, 5], 9, 2, "#00FF00")
    this.player2 = player2; //new player([5, 5], 9, 2, "#00FF00")
    this.tokens = tokens; //[[new token("#0000FF", 5), false],
                      // [new token("#0000FF", 5), false]]
}
```

The token array has "false" for any empty squares, and tokens[a][b] is
the token at x = a, y = b, numbered starting from the upper-left corner.

**Controller:**
[Here's](https://github.com/allenkev/annieflow/blob/master/aicomp.html) a link to the controller in GitHub. It's an html file that you can run to see how the game and the round-robin works, and it comes with two AIs, a random one that moves in a random direction each turn but eats tokens at its position, and a naive algorithm that goes for the nearest token that gives the most points. I will add in each AI as it is submitted.

Below is a snippet that allows you to run the controller on the default AI.
Current AIs:

- KindaRandomAI
- NaiveAI
- MirrorBot
- HungryBot

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="600" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>

  <script>
    // AI Array, put in at least two constructor functions as described in the
     // data file, and it will do round robin on them.
     // Also, you can adjust some variables for testing purposes only.
    var interval = 1; // in milliseconds per turn
    var matches = 10; // number of matches for each pairing
    var aiArray = [];
    myAI = function(player1) {
      this.player1 = player1;
      this.yourMove = function(b) {
        var me;
        if (this.player1) {
          me = b.player1;
        } else {
          me = b.player2;
        }
        var d = 0;
        var tokenP;
        while (tokenP == undefined) {
          var arr = this.findTokensAtDistance(me.pos, d)
          tokenP = this.findBestToken(arr, b.tokens, me);
          d += 1;
        }
        return this.startAndGoalToCommand(me.pos, tokenP);
      }
      this.findTokensAtDistance = function(p, d) {
        if (d == 0) {
          return [
            [p[0], p[1]]
          ];
        }
        var myArr = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= d; i++) {
          myArr[i] = [i, d - i];
        }
        var mySecArr = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= d; i++) {
          mySecArr[i] = [myArr[i][0] + p[0], myArr[i][1] + p[1]];
        }
        mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [myArr[0][0] + p[0], -myArr[0][1] + p[1]];
        for (i = 1; i < myArr.length - 1; i++) {
          mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [-myArr[i][0] + p[0], myArr[i][1] + p[1]]
          mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [myArr[i][0] + p[0], -myArr[i][1] + p[1]]
          mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [-myArr[i][0] + p[0], -myArr[i][1] + p[1]]
        }
        mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [-myArr[myArr.length - 1][0] + p[0], myArr[myArr.length - 1][1] + p[1]];
        return mySecArr;
      }
      this.findBestToken = function(arr, t, player) {
        var tokenPos;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i][0] >= 0 && arr[i][0] < t.length && arr[i][1] >= 0 && arr[i][1] < t.length) {
            if (t[arr[i][0]][arr[i][1]] != false && ((tokenPos == undefined) || (this.tokenScore(player, t[arr[i][0]][arr[i][1]]) > this.tokenScore(player, t[tokenPos[0]][tokenPos[1]])))) {
              tokenPos = [arr[i][0],
                [arr[i][1]]
              ];
            }
          }
        }
        return tokenPos;
      }
      this.tokenScore = function(player, token) {
        if (player.lastColor == token.color) {
          return player.colorBonus + 1 + token.points;
        } else {
          return token.points;
        }
      }
      this.startAndGoalToCommand = function(start, goal) {
        var diff = [goal[0] - start[0], goal[1] - start[1]];
        if (diff[0] > 0) {
          return "RIGHT";
        } else if (diff[1] > 0) {
          return "DOWN";
        } else if (diff[1] < 0) {
          return "UP";
        } else if (diff[0] < 0) {
          return "LEFT";
        } else {
          return "EAT";
        }
      }
    }
    aiArray[0] = myAI;
     // This is a really stupid AI, used to test that the round-robin selected
     // it is the worst by far
    myStupidAI = function(player1) {
      this.player1 = player1;
      this.yourMove = function(b) {
        var me;
        if (this.player1) {
          me = b.player1;
        } else {
          me = b.player2;
        }
        if (b.tokens[me.pos[0]][me.pos[1]] != false) {
          return "EAT";
        } else {
          var dirs = this.getViableDirections(b, me.pos);
          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * dirs.length);
          return dirs[rand];
        }
      }
      this.getViableDirections = function(b, p) {
        var dirs = [];
        if (p[0] > 0) {
          dirs.push("LEFT");
        }
        if (p[1] > 0) {
          dirs.push("UP");
        }
        if (p[1] < b.tokens.length - 1) {
          dirs.push("DOWN");
        }
        if (p[0] < b.tokens.length - 1) {
          dirs.push("RIGHT");
        }
        return dirs;
      }
    }
    aiArray[1] = myStupidAI;
    mirrorBot = function(player1){
        this.hasStarted=0;
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.yourMove = function(b){
            this.op = this.player1 ? b.player2 : b.player1;
            var out = "EAT";
            if(this.hasStarted){
                if(this.opl.pos[0] < this.op.pos[0]) out = "LEFT";
                if(this.opl.pos[0] > this.op.pos[0]) out = "RIGHT";
                if(this.opl.pos[1] < this.op.pos[1]) out = "UP";
                if(this.opl.pos[1] > this.op.pos[1]) out = "DOWN";
            }
            this.opl = this.op;
            this.hasStarted = 1;
            return out;
        }
    }
    aiArray[2] = mirrorBot;
    hungryBot = function(first) {
  // Set up "self"
  var self = this;

  // Determine player order
  this.player = -(first - 2);
  this.enemy = first + 1;

  // Action associative array
  this.actions = ['EAT', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'UP', 'DOWN'];

  //Logic handler
  this.yourMove = function(board) {
// Determine player object
var player = board['player' + self.player];
var enemy = board['player' + self.enemy];

// Point value action grid
var actions = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // Associative with "this.actions"

// Board dimensions
var size = board.tokens.length;
var maxDist = size * 2;

// Colors remaining
var colors = {
  '#FF0000': 0,
  '#00FF00': 0,
  '#0000FF': 0
};

// Averaged value weight
var average = [0, 0];

// Total points
var points = 0;

// Token holder
var tokens = [];

// Token parser
for (var i = 0, x = 0, y = 0; i < size * size; i += 1, x = i % size, y = i / size | 0) {
  if (!board.tokens[x][y]) {
    continue;
  } else {
    var token = {};
    token.points = board.tokens[x][y].points;
    token.color = board.tokens[x][y].color;
    token.x = x - player.pos[0];
    token.y = y - player.pos[1];
    token.distX = Math.abs(token.x);
    token.distY = Math.abs(token.y);
    token.dist = token.distX + token.distY;
    token.distE = Math.abs(x - enemy.pos[0]) + Math.abs(y - enemy.pos[1]);
    token.value = -token.points - (player.colorBonus + 1) * (token.color == player.lastColor) * ((token.dist == 0) + 1) * 1.618 - (enemy.colorBonus + 1) * (token.color == enemy.lastColor);
    tokens.push(token);
    colors[token.color] += 1;
    points += token.points;
    average[0] += x * token.points;
    average[1] += y * token.points;
  }
}

// Determine actual average
average[0] = average[0] / points | 0;
average[1] = average[1] / points | 0;

// Pick best token
var best = 0;

// Calculate point values of tokens
for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  var token = tokens[i];
  // Add remaining numbers of tokens of color as factor
  token.value -= (colors[token.color] / tokens.length) * 1.618;
  // Subtract distance as a factor
  token.value += token.dist;
  // Add distance to average to value
  token.value += (Math.abs(average[0] - (token.x + player.pos[0])) + Math.abs(average[1] - (token.y + player.pos[1]))) / Math.sqrt(2);
  // Consider them higher value if we are closer, and lower if they are
  token.value += ((token.dist - token.distE) / (token.dist + token.distE + 0.001)) * token.dist;
  // Don't go for it if enemy is already there
  token.value += (token.distE == 0 && token.dist > 0) * 100;

  if (tokens[best].value > tokens[i].value || (tokens[best].value === tokens[i].value && Math.round(Math.random()))) {
    best = i;
  }
}

// Set token to best token
var token = tokens[best];

// What to respond with
var response = 'PASS';

// Find best action to get token
if (token.dist == 0) {
  response = 'EAT'; // We're on the token
} else if (token.distX >= token.distY) { // Token is more horizontal
  if (token.x < 0) { // Token is left
    response = 'LEFT';
  } else if (token.x > 0) { // Token is right
    response = 'RIGHT';
  }
} else if (token.distX < token.distY) { // Token is more vertical
  if (token.y < 0) { // Token is above
    response = 'UP';
  } else if (token.y > 0) { // Token is below
    response = 'DOWN';
  }
}

// Return response
return response;
  }
};
    aiArray[3]=hungryBot;
    for (i = 0; i < aiArray.length; i += 1) {
      Object.freeze(aiArray[i]);
    }
     // This is the actual code to run the program. You shouldn't mess with it,
     // or your AI might not work during the actual competition.
     // Also note that you can't access this code at all in your AI.
     // Feel free to make suggestions and we'll try to incorporate them,
     // and let us know if something isn't working correctly.
    Object.freeze(aiArray);
    setInterval((function() {
      function token(color, points) {
        this.color = color;
        this.points = points;
      }

      function player(pos, score, colorBonus, lastColor) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.score = score;
        this.colorBonus = colorBonus;
        this.lastColor = lastColor;
      }

      function board(player1, player2, tokens) {
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
        this.tokens = tokens;
      }

      function copyBoard(b) {
        return new board(copyPlayer(b.player1), copyPlayer(b.player2), copyTokens(b.tokens));
      }

      function copyTokens(t) {
        var tokens = [];
        for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
          tokens[i] = [];
          for (j = 0; j < t[i].length; j++) {
            tokens[i][j] = t[i][j];
          }
        }
        return tokens;
      }

      function copyPlayer(p) {
        return new player([p.pos[0], p.pos[1]], p.score, p.colorBonus, p.lastColor);
      }

      function endGame(b) {
        if (b.player1.score > b.player2.score) {
          var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
          ctx.font = 20 + "px Arial";
          ctx.textAlign = "left";
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
          ctx.fillText("Player 1", 601, 160);
          ctx.fillText("wins!", 601, 180);
        } else if (b.player1.score < b.player2.score) {
          var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
          ctx.font = 20 + "px Arial";
          ctx.textAlign = "left";
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
          ctx.fillText("Player 2", 601, 160);
          ctx.fillText("wins!", 601, 180);
        } else {
          var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
          ctx.font = 20 + "px Arial";
          ctx.textAlign = "left";
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
          ctx.fillText("It's a", 601, 160);
          ctx.fillText("draw!", 601, 180);
        }
      }

      function genTokenArray(size) {
        var temp = [];
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          temp[i] = [];
          for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = false;
          }
        }
        return temp;
      }

      function genRandomTokenArray(size) {
        var temp = genTokenArray(size);
        for (i = 0; i < size * 2; i++) {
          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length);
          var points = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
          var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
          var color;
          var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp[rand].length);
          if (rand2 == 0) {
            color = "#FF0000"
          } else if (rand2 == 1) {
            color = "#00FF00"
          } else {
            color = "#0000FF"
          }
          temp[rand][rand3] = new token(color, points);
        }
        return temp;
      }

      function countTokens(tokenArr) {
        var x = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < tokenArr.length; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < tokenArr[i].length; j++) {
            if (tokenArr[i][j] != false) {
              x += 1
            }
          }
        }
        return x;
      }

      function actPlayer(b, p, s) {
        if (s == "UP" && p.pos[1] > 0) {
          p.pos[1] -= 1;
        } else if (s == "RIGHT" && p.pos[0] < b.tokens.length - 1) {
          p.pos[0] += 1;
        } else if (s == "DOWN" && p.pos[1] < b.tokens.length - 1) {
          p.pos[1] += 1;
        } else if (s == "LEFT" && p.pos[0] > 0) {
          p.pos[0] -= 1;
        } else if (s == "EAT" && b.tokens[p.pos[0]][p.pos[1]] != false) {
          if (p.lastColor == b.tokens[p.pos[0]][p.pos[1]].color) {
            p.colorBonus += 1;
            p.score += p.colorBonus;
          } else {
            p.lastColor = b.tokens[p.pos[0]][p.pos[1]].color;
            p.colorBonus = 0;
          }
          p.score += b.tokens[p.pos[0]][p.pos[1]].points;
          b.tokens[p.pos[0]][p.pos[1]] = false;
        }
      }

      function drawEmptyRect() {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 600);
      }

      function drawToken(t, x, y, g) {
        drawEntity(x, y, t.points, t.color, "#000000", 300 / g, g);
      }

      function drawLittleEntity(x, y, label, fillColor, labelColor, size, cX, cY, g) {
        var delta = 600 / g;
        var x1 = x * delta + cX * delta / 4;
        var y1 = y * delta + cY * delta / 4;
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x1, y1, size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font = delta / 2 + "px Arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillStyle = labelColor;
        ctx.fillText(label, x1, y1 + delta * 3 / 16);
      }

      function drawEntity(x, y, label, fillColor, labelColor, size, g) {
        var delta = 600 / g;
        var x1 = x * delta + delta / 2;
        var y1 = y * delta + delta / 2;
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x1, y1, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font = delta + "px Arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillStyle = labelColor;
        ctx.fillText(label, x1, y1 + delta * 3 / 8);
      }

      function drawAllTokens(arrToken) {
        for (i = 0; i < arrToken.length; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < arrToken[i].length; j++) {
            if (arrToken[i][j] != false) {
              drawToken(arrToken[i][j], i, j, arrToken.length);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function drawGrid(g) {
        var delta = 600 / g;
        for (i = 0; i <= g; i++) {
          var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(i * delta, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(i * delta, 600);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
        for (j = 0; j <= g; j++) {
          var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(0, j * delta);
          ctx.lineTo(600, j * delta);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      }

      function drawPlayer1(b, g) {
        drawLittleEntity(b.player1.pos[0], b.player1.pos[1], "F", "#000000", "#FFFFFF", 300 / g, 1, 1, g);
      }

      function drawPlayer2(b, g) {
        drawLittleEntity(b.player2.pos[0], b.player2.pos[1], "S", "#000000", "#FFFFFF", 300 / g, 3, 3, g);
      }

      function drawScore(b) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "20px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.fillText("P" + indices[0] + " Score:", 601, 50);
        ctx.fillText(b.player1.score, 601, 70);
        ctx.fillText("P" + indices[1] + " Score:", 601, 100);
        ctx.fillText(b.player2.score, 601, 120);
      }

      function drawScoreNum(s, i) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "20px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.fillText("P" + i + " Score:", 601, i * 50 + 50);
        ctx.fillText(s, 601, i * 50 + 70);
      }

      function redraw(b, g) {
        drawEmptyRect();
        drawGrid(g);
        drawScore(b);
        drawAllTokens(b.tokens);
        drawPlayer1(b, g);
        drawPlayer2(b, g);
        drawScoreNum()
      }

      function nextPair(pair, total) {
        var pairRes = [pair[0], (pair[1] + 1) % total];
        if (pairRes[1] == 0) {
          pairRes[0] = pairRes[0] + 1;
        }
        return pairRes;
      }

      function nextGameUnfair() {
        scores[indices[0]] = scores[indices[0]] + currBoard.player1.score;
        scores[indices[1]] = scores[indices[1]] + currBoard.player2.score;
        if (matchCount >= matches) {
          matchCount = 0;
          indices = nextPair(indices, aiArray.length);
          if (indices[0] == indices[1]) {
            indices = nextPair(indices, aiArray.length);
          }
          if (indices[0] >= aiArray.length) {
            return false;
          }
          player1Turn = true;
          timeWithoutEating = 0;
          firstAI = new aiArray[indices[0]](true);
          secondAI = new aiArray[indices[1]](false);
          currBoard = genBoard();
        } else {
          matchCount++;
          player1Turn = true;
          timeWithoutEating = 0;
          firstAI = new aiArray[indices[0]](true);
          secondAI = new aiArray[indices[1]](false);
          currBoard = genBoard();
        }
        return true;
      }

      function nextGameFair() {
        scores[indices[0]] = scores[indices[0]] + currBoard.player1.score;
        scores[indices[1]] = scores[indices[1]] + currBoard.player2.score;
        indices = nextPair(indices, aiArray.length);
        if (indices[0] == indices[1]) {
          indices = nextPair(indices, aiArray.length);
        }
        if (indices[0] >= aiArray.length) {
          indices = [0, 1];
          matchCount++;
          if (matchCount >= matches) {
            return false;
          }
          player1Turn = true;
          timeWithoutEating = 0;
          currBoard = genBoard();
        } else {
          player1Turn = true;
          timeWithoutEating = 0;
          currBoard = savedBoard;
        }
        firstAI = new aiArray[indices[0]](true);
        secondAI = new aiArray[indices[1]](false);
        savedBoard = copyBoard(currBoard);
        return true;
      }

      function genBoard() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 5);
        var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * rand);
        var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * rand);
        return new board(new player([randX, randY], 0, 0, "#000000"),
          new player([randX, randY], 0, 0, "#000000"),
          genRandomTokenArray(rand));
      }
      var running = true;
      var indices = [0, 1];
      var scores = []
      for (i = 0; i < aiArray.length; i++) {
        scores.push(0);
      }
      var matchCount = 0;
      var firstAI = new aiArray[0](true);
      var secondAI = new aiArray[1](false);
      var player1Turn = true;
      var currBoard = genBoard();
      var savedBoard = copyBoard(currBoard);
      var timeWithoutEating = 0;
      return function() {
        if (running) {
          var numTokens = countTokens(currBoard.tokens);
          if (numTokens <= 0) {} else if (player1Turn) {
            actPlayer(currBoard, currBoard.player1, firstAI.yourMove(copyBoard(currBoard)));
          } else {
            actPlayer(currBoard, currBoard.player2, secondAI.yourMove(copyBoard(currBoard)));
          }
          player1Turn = !player1Turn;
          redraw(currBoard, currBoard.tokens.length);
          if (numTokens > countTokens(currBoard.tokens)) {
            timeWithoutEating = 0;
          } else {
            timeWithoutEating += 1;
          }
          if (numTokens <= 0 || timeWithoutEating > 4 * currBoard.tokens.length) {
            running = nextGameFair();
          }
        } else {
          drawEmptyRect();
          for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            drawScoreNum(scores[i], i);
          }
        }
      }
    })(), interval);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yay, a KOTH! It has been forever since the last one.

Comment: Agreed, I love me a good KOTH and this seems to be a great premise. I'm a bit green to js, how does one persist game state between moves if we can't save results within out player object?

Comment: Is the board width passed anywhere into the function?

Comment: @BentNeeHumor Yes, the function that takes in the `player1` boolean is the constructor for your AI, which will have a `yourMove` function that takes the current board as input, as `b`.

Comment: @DoctorHeckle Refer to previous comment, the constructor for example could say `this.yourMove = function (b) {//do stuff with b;this.lastBoard=b}` and `this.lastBoard` will give you the last board.

Comment: It could be nice to make your naive AI compete, to serve as reference. And for the lulz! ;) (I guess random would skew the results, but the lol factor would be even better)

Comment: I haven't participated in a KOTH here before; are multiple submissions ok, or is it one per user?

Comment: @DylanSp Sometimes they aren't allowed due to collusion possibilities, but in this case, collusion would have minimal benefits, so I'll allow multiple submissions.

Comment: Is `player.colorBonus` equal to the next color bonus you will earn, or the previous one earned?

Comment: @Blue http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77235/koth-everybody-loves-tokens#comment188351_77235

Comment: @BentNeeHumor The previous one, so if you eat two Blue in a row, player.colorBonus==1, and when you eat another Blue, you get +2 and the bonus increases by 1

Comment: Would it be 0 if the previous color was different?

Comment: @BentNeeHumor Yes. It starts out 0 (and lastColor starts as "#000000", different from any color on the board) and is reset to 0 whenever a different color than the previous one is eaten.

Comment: Is the board wrap-around or bounded at the edges? If the latter, does a move of LEFT when you are at the LHS of the board, for example, count as equivalent to PASS?

Comment: @Penguino Bounded, working like you say it does, updated post to indicate that.

Comment: As someone mentioned before, you should submit your own bots as answers. It allows for individual questions/commentary, and for reference as people build their own bots.

Comment: Do the [claims of teleportation](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77235/koth-everybody-loves-tokens#comment188792_77412) indicate a problem with the controller?

Comment: @trichoplax No, it turned out to be a problem with my AI, the controller is fine.

Comment: @Blue Ah OK. I was thinking that the controller had permitted your AI to make the mentioned teleport moves.

Comment: The [video](https://youtu.be/BIhSKycF9iA) does make it look like the controller is permitting the bot to teleport, suggesting a problem with the controller itself.

Comment: @trichoplax The board is deep-copied before being given to the bots, so as long as the copying is correct, it can't be the bots somehow affecting the board by mistake.

Comment: Yes the bot alone shouldn't be able to make this happen. The linked video does seem to indicate a problem with the controller itself, but I can't guess how it is happening.

Comment: Also, the snippet is too long if I add the next AI. What's the best way to move the code elsewhere and still put it in the snippet?

Comment: Host individual files on GitHub pages maybe. That way it will also be a little easier to read.

Comment: So... who wins? :3

Comment: Is there a page that explains how KOTH works?

Comment: Is the contest still on? Which languages can be used?

Answer (score 4):

## HungryBot

Uses a point system to add weight to the value of pursuing each token. Uses a variety of different factors in its consideration, and reevaluates them each turn to ensure its following the best strategy.

```js
function hungryBot(first) {
  // Set up "self"
  var self = this;
  
  // Determine player order
  this.player = -(first - 2);
  this.enemy = first + 1;
  
  // Action associative array
  this.actions = ['EAT', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'UP', 'DOWN'];
  
  //Logic handler
  this.yourMove = function(board) {
    // Determine player object
    var player = board['player' + self.player];
    var enemy = board['player' + self.enemy];
    
    // Point value action grid
    var actions = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // Associative with "this.actions"
    
    // Board dimensions
    var size = board.tokens.length;
    var maxDist = size * 2;
    
    // Colors remaining
    var colors = {
      '#FF0000': 0,
      '#00FF00': 0,
      '#0000FF': 0
    };
    
    // Averaged value weight
    var average = [0, 0];
    
    // Total points
    var points = 0;
    
    // Token holder
    var tokens = [];
    
    // Token parser
    for (var i = 0, x = 0, y = 0; i < size * size; i += 1, x = i % size, y = i / size | 0) {
      if (!board.tokens[x][y]) {
        continue;
      } else {
        var token = {};
        token.points = board.tokens[x][y].points;
        token.color = board.tokens[x][y].color;
        token.x = x - player.pos[0];
        token.y = y - player.pos[1];
        token.distX = Math.abs(token.x);
        token.distY = Math.abs(token.y);
        token.dist = token.distX + token.distY;
        token.distE = Math.abs(x - enemy.pos[0]) + Math.abs(y - enemy.pos[1]);
        token.value = -token.points - (player.colorBonus + 1) * (token.color == player.lastColor) * ((token.dist == 0) + 1) * 1.618 - (enemy.colorBonus + 1) * (token.color == enemy.lastColor);
        tokens.push(token);
        colors[token.color] += 1;
        points += token.points;
        average[0] += x * token.points;
        average[1] += y * token.points;
      }
    }
    
    // Determine actual average
    average[0] = average[0] / points | 0;
    average[1] = average[1] / points | 0;
    
    // Pick best token
    var best = 0;
    
    // Calculate point values of tokens
    for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
      var token = tokens[i];
      // Add remaining numbers of tokens of color as factor
      token.value -= (colors[token.color] / tokens.length) * 1.618;
      // Subtract distance as a factor
      token.value += token.dist;
      // Add distance to average to value
      token.value += (Math.abs(average[0] - (token.x + player.pos[0])) + Math.abs(average[1] - (token.y + player.pos[1]))) / Math.sqrt(2);
      // Consider them higher value if we are closer, and lower if they are
      token.value += ((token.dist - token.distE) / (token.dist + token.distE + 0.001)) * token.dist;
      // Don't go for it if enemy is already there
      token.value += (token.distE == 0 && token.dist > 0) * 100;
      
      if (tokens[best].value > tokens[i].value || (tokens[best].value === tokens[i].value && Math.round(Math.random()))) {
        best = i;
      }
    }
    
    // Set token to best token
    var token = tokens[best];
    
    // What to respond with
    var response = 'PASS';
    
    // Find best action to get token
    if (token.dist == 0) {
      response = 'EAT'; // We're on the token
    } else if (token.distX >= token.distY) { // Token is more horizontal
      if (token.x < 0) { // Token is left
        response = 'LEFT';
      } else if (token.x > 0) { // Token is right
        response = 'RIGHT';
      }
    } else if (token.distX < token.distY) { // Token is more vertical
      if (token.y < 0) { // Token is above
        response = 'UP';
      } else if (token.y > 0) { // Token is below
        response = 'DOWN';
      }
    }
    
    // Return response
    return response;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you a Python programmer?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Not really...?

Comment: Just thought you were because `self` :)

Comment: Why use `self`? Isn't `this` sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

## PATH bot

Acronym stands for Pathfinding And Tree Heuristics Bot

**EDIT:** As of now, here are the rankings for the AIs, with the points

1. HungryBot (6422)
2. PATH bot (4591)
3. NaiveAI (3811)
4. KindaRandomAI (618)
5. MirrorBot (193)
6. LazyBot (25)

Link to complete controller [on github](https://github.com/jediguy13/annieflow/blob/master/aicomp_full.html)

Description: Like NaiveAI, this bot finds the nearest token that will give it the most points. However, it also simulates the outcomes of each of its moves, up to 6 times.

Rationale: Because NaiveAI is already pretty good, I though I would make it better. Without looking at the code first (big mistake).

Beats: All except HungryBot
Looses to: None except HungryBot

Problems:

- Cannot simulate increased streak
- Hangs while calculating best token
- <s>Can teleport</s>

I still don't know why it was teleporting, but I fixed it. Old video here: https://youtu.be/BIhSKycF9iA

Full code:

```
pathBot = function (player1)
{
    this.pathNode = function(pos,ppt,parents,par)
    {
        this.pos = pos;this.ppt = ppt;this.parents = parents;this.par=par;
        this.childs=[];
    }
    this.addChildren = function (pn,children)
    {
        pn.childs=[];
        for(var i=0; i<children.length; i=i+1)
        {
            if(pn.parents.indexOf(children[i].pos)==-1&&pn.pos!=children[i].pos)
                pn.childs.push(
                    new this.pathNode(
                        children[i].pos,
                        children[i].ppt*pn.ppt,
                        pn.parents.concat([pn.pos]),
                        pn
                    )
                );
        }
    }
    this.orderTokensByPPT = function(b,pos){
        var tokens = [];
        for(var y=0; y<b.tokens.length; y=y+1)
        {
            for(var x=0; x<b.tokens[y].length; x=x+1)
            {
                var tok = b.tokens[y][x];
                if(tok)
                {
                    tokens.push(
                        new this.pathNode(
                            [y,x],
                            (tok.points+(tok.color==this.color ? this.streak : 0)) / this.lenOfMovesTo(pos,[y,x]),
                            [],
                            undefined
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        tokens.sort(function(a,b){
            return b.ppt - a.ppt;
        });
        return tokens;
    }
    this.lenOfMovesTo = function(cur,pos)
    {
        return Math.abs(cur[0]-pos[0])+Math.abs(cur[1]-pos[1])+1;
    }
    this.startAndGoalToCommand = function (start, goal) {
        var diff = [goal[0] - start[0], goal[1] - start[1]];
        if (diff[0] > 0) { return "RIGHT"; }
        else if (diff[1] > 0) { return "DOWN"; }
        else if (diff[1] < 0) { return "UP"; }
        else if (diff[0] < 0) { return "LEFT"; }
        else { return "EAT"; }
    }
    this.color = 0;
    this.streak = 0;
    this.eatTok = function(b)
    {
        if(b.tokens[this.me.pos[0]][this.me.pos[1]].color==this.color)
        {
            this.streak++;
        }
        else{
            this.streak = 0;
            this.color = b.tokens[this.me.pos[0]][this.me.pos[1]].color;
        }
        this.bestToken = false;
        return "EAT";
    }

    this.recurLen = 6;
    this.include = 4;
    this.recurDown = function(b,pn,level)
    {
        if(level==0) return pn;
        this.addChildren(pn,this.orderTokensByPPT(b,pn.pos));
        var newChilds = [];
        for(var i=0; i<pn.childs.length&&i<this.include; i=i+1)
        {
            newChilds.push(this.recurDown(b,pn.childs[i],level-1));
        }
        pn.childs = newChilds;
        return pn;
    }
    this.findMax = function(pn)
    {
        if(pn.childs)
        {
            var maxList = [];
            for(var i=0; i<pn.childs.length; i=i+1)
                maxList.push(this.findMax(pn.childs[i]));
            maxList.sort(
                function(a,b)
                {
                    return b.ppt-a.ppt;
                }
            );
            return maxList[0];
        }
        return pn;
    }
    this.findMaxList = function(pnList)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<pnList.lenght; i=i+1)
        {
            pnList[i] = this.findMax(pnList[i]);
        }
        pnList.sort(function(a,b){return b.ppt-a.ppt;});
        return pnList[0];
    }
    this.bestToken=false;
    this.yourMove = function(b){
        this.op = player1 ? b.player2 : b.player1;
        this.me = player1 ? b.player1 : b.player2;
        if(this.bestToken)
        {
            if(b.tokens[this.bestToken.pos[0]][this.bestToken.pos[1]]==undefined)
                this.bestToken = false;
        }
        if(!this.bestToken)
        {
            var paths = this.orderTokensByPPT(b,this.me.pos);
            for(var i=0; i<paths.length; i++)
            {
                paths[i] = this.recurDown(b,paths[i],this.recurLen);
            }
            var max = this.findMaxList(paths);
            while(max.par)
            {
                max = max.par;
            }
            this.bestToken = max;
        }
        var move = this.startAndGoalToCommand(this.me.pos,this.bestToken.pos);
        if(move=="EAT") return this.eatTok(b);
        else return move;
    }
}
```

Comment: SLaNTbot is slowing the turn speed down, and eating up 15% of my CPU... D: EDIT: And also not eating anything?

Comment: @Mwr247 the speed, yeah, it models ~2500 possibilities every tick. But for the eating thing, I don't exactly know why. Like I said in the question, it just teleports (aka moves multiple spaces in 1 turn), and sits there doing nothing. I put an alert just before the return and it seems to be giving the right instructions every time.

Comment: Maybe this: "Your AI should take less than a second to make a move, else PASS will be assumed as your choice.". I haven't read the controller, but if it's taking over a second, is it assuming PASS?

Comment: @Mwr247 I'll look into that, but it seems unlikely given that it was taking <1 second (or so I though) on my machine. Still, never hurts to look. Thank you!

Comment: @Mwr247 After some more testing, that is not it. It is making decisions almost as fast (at least for me) as NaiveAi. Also, you are more likely to experience teleportation on big maps

Answer (score 1):

## MirrorBot

Should be called "cannon fodder"

Description: Moves the exact opposite of what the other player did

Rationale: I wanted to get comfortable programming in JS again. This should not win

Will beat: No one

Will lose to: Everyone

```
function mirror(player1) {
    this.hasStarted=false;
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.opl=[0,0];
    this.yourMove = function(b){
        this.op = this.player1 ? b.player2.pos : b.player1.pos;
        out = "EAT";
        console.log(this.op);
        console.log(this.opl);
        if(this.hasStarted){
            if(this.opl[0] < this.op[0]) out = "RIGHT";
            if(this.opl[0] > this.op[0]) out = "LEFT";
            if(this.opl[1] < this.op[1]) out = "UP";
            if(this.opl[1] > this.op[1]) out = "DOWN";
        }
        this.opl = [this.op[0],this.op[1]];
        this.hasStarted = true;
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your code. Right and Left aren't opposite, and your function definition for yourMove isn't valid syntax. My code was broken before as well, so in the process of finding and fixing the problem in my code I fixed your code as well. You can look at the fixed code in my script.

Comment: @FricativeMelon I fixed the broken function definition. I have to counter the claim that right aren't opposite.

Comment: 0,0 is the top-left corner, so positive x is right and negative x is left. if the new x-pos is greater in value than the old x-pos, the other player moved right, so you should move left, and vice-versa. Also, you should use `var out = "EAT";` instead of `out = "EAT";`, since the later defines a global variable. Nitpicking a bit, the third and fourth lines don't do anything and can be removed as well, and `op` can be a local variable like `out` instead of a property.

Comment: @FricativeMelon ah, I get what you are saying. I have updated the code. Thank you!

Comment: I put your new code in the script, and it's working now. Doesn't beat RandomAI though :(

Answer (score 1):

## KindaRandomAI

Every turn, do the following:
If there is a token at your position, "EAT".
Otherwise, move in a random viable direction, i.e. if you're at the left edge don't say "LEFT".

```
kindaRandomAI = function(player1) {
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.yourMove = function(b) {
        var me;
        if (this.player1) {
            me = b.player1;
        } else {
            me = b.player2;
        }
        if (b.tokens[me.pos[0]][me.pos[1]] != false) {
            return "EAT";
        } else {
            var dirs = this.getViableDirections(b, me.pos);
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * dirs.length);
            return dirs[rand];
        }
    }
    this.getViableDirections = function(b, p) {
        var dirs = [];
        if (p[0] > 0) {
            dirs.push("LEFT");
        }
        if (p[1] > 0) {
            dirs.push("UP");
        }
        if (p[1] < b.tokens.length - 1) {
            dirs.push("DOWN");
        }
        if (p[0] < b.tokens.length - 1) {
            dirs.push("RIGHT");
        }
        return dirs;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 not completely random

Comment: That's better!.

Answer (score 1):

## NaiveAI

Starting with `r=0`, look at all tokens with taxicab distance `r` away from your position. If there are any, pick one that would give you the highest score if you got it right now. Otherwise, increase `r` by 1 and try again.

```
naiveAI = function(player1) {
  this.player1 = player1;
  this.yourMove = function(b) {
    var me;
    if (this.player1) {
      me = b.player1;
    } else {
      me = b.player2;
    }
    var d = 0;
    var tokenP;
    while (tokenP == undefined) {
      var arr = this.findTokensAtDistance(me.pos, d)
      tokenP = this.findBestToken(arr, b.tokens, me);
      d += 1;
    }
    return this.startAndGoalToCommand(me.pos, tokenP);
  }
  this.findTokensAtDistance = function(p, d) {
    if (d == 0) {
      return [
        [p[0], p[1]]
      ];
    }
    var myArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= d; i++) {
      myArr[i] = [i, d - i];
    }
    var mySecArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= d; i++) {
      mySecArr[i] = [myArr[i][0] + p[0], myArr[i][1] + p[1]];
    }
    mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [myArr[0][0] + p[0], -myArr[0][1] + p[1]];
    for (i = 1; i < myArr.length - 1; i++) {
      mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [-myArr[i][0] + p[0], myArr[i][1] + p[1]]
      mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [myArr[i][0] + p[0], -myArr[i][1] + p[1]]
      mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [-myArr[i][0] + p[0], -myArr[i][1] + p[1]]
    }
    mySecArr[mySecArr.length] = [-myArr[myArr.length - 1][0] + p[0], myArr[myArr.length - 1][1] + p[1]];
    return mySecArr;
  }
  this.findBestToken = function(arr, t, player) {
    var tokenPos;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i][0] >= 0 && arr[i][0] < t.length && arr[i][1] >= 0 && arr[i][1] < t.length) {
        if (t[arr[i][0]][arr[i][1]] != false && ((tokenPos == undefined) || (this.tokenScore(player, t[arr[i][0]][arr[i][1]]) > this.tokenScore(player, t[tokenPos[0]][tokenPos[1]])))) {
          tokenPos = [arr[i][0],
            [arr[i][1]]
          ];
        }
      }
    }
    return tokenPos;
  }
  this.tokenScore = function(player, token) {
    if (player.lastColor == token.color) {
      return player.colorBonus + 1 + token.points;
    } else {
      return token.points;
    }
  }
  this.startAndGoalToCommand = function(start, goal) {
    var diff = [goal[0] - start[0], goal[1] - start[1]];
    if (diff[0] > 0) {
      return "RIGHT";
    } else if (diff[1] > 0) {
      return "DOWN";
    } else if (diff[1] < 0) {
      return "UP";
    } else if (diff[0] < 0) {
      return "LEFT";
    } else {
      return "EAT";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## LazyBot

Only eats something if he spawns on it.
This has no chance to win, but the challenge didn't have one of these, so why not.

```
lazyBot = function (player1) {
    this.yourMove = function(b) {
        return "EAT";
    }
}
```

Comment: Every koth has an EmoWolf...

Comment: @Blue It's not 100% emo, it tries to eat.

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1916#1916

Answer (score 0):

## OneTarget

Finds the token that will give the most points in the least time and will go for that one. Ranks same color tokens a little higher because of the cumulative effect.

```
function (player1) {
    this.yourMove = function (b) {
        var me = player1? b.player1: b.player2;
        var him= player1? b.player2: b.player1;
        var x = me.pos[0];
        var y = me.pos[1];
        var maxVal = -1;
        var maxX = 0;
        var maxY = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i < b.tokens.length;i++){
            for(var j = 0;j < b.tokens.length;j++){
                if(b.tokens[i][j]){
                    var dist = Math.abs(x-i) + Math.abs(y-j);
                    var val = this.valueOf(b.tokens[i][j]);
                    val /= (dist + 1);
                    if(val > maxVal){
                        maxVal = val;
                        maxX = i;
                        maxY = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(maxY < y)
            return "UP";
        if(maxX < x)
            return "LEFT";
        if(maxY > y)
            return "DOWN";
        if(maxX > x)
            return "RIGHT";
        return "EAT";
    }
    this.valueOf = function(t){
        //how many points would it give you?
        return t.points + (this.lastColor == t.color? 2 * this.colorBonus + 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### QuantityPlayer

All QuantityPlayer cares about is the amout of dots he eats, not the value or color of the dots. He know that even though all dots are different, they should be treated the same.

```
QuantityBot = function(playernum) {

this.dist = function(token) {
    return (Math.abs(token[0])+Math.abs(token[1]))
}

this.yourMove = function(game_board) {

    board_size = game_board.tokens.length
    board_area = board_size * board_size
    fete = board_size = size * 2

    token_list = []
    count = curr_x = curr_y = 0
    while(count < board_area) {
        if(game_board.tokens[x][y]) {
        token_list.push([x-player.pos[0],y-player.pos[1]])
        }
        count++; x = count % board_size; y = Math.floor(count / size)
    }

    closest_token = token_list[0]
    count = 1
    while(count < token_list.length) {
        curr_token = token_list[count]
        if(dist(curr_token) < dist(closest_token)){closest_token = curr_token}

        count++
    }

    if(dist(closest_token)==0){return 'EAT'}
    else{
    if(closest_token[0] >= closest_token[1]) {if(closest_token[0]<0) {return 'LEFT'} {return 'RIGHT'}}
    else{if(closest_token[1]<0) {return 'UP'} {return 'DOWN'}}
    }

}

}
```